# How to show tableview when user taps searchbar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I need a tableview to be presented modally after user taps on the search bar, and then be able to have the tableview present things the user searched, like Instagram's search function. There are plenty of tutorials on google about how to make a search feature, but none about how to present a tableview after the user taps on the search bar. How should I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference between what you want and between what it is explained [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial)

Comment: In that example, the search bar is in a tableview. My search bar is in a collectionview, and I want a tableview to be presented after the user taps on the search bar.

Comment: So you could add a TableView to your controller and you make it not hidden everytime the user search something in the searchBar ?

Comment: @Chajmz That doesnt work because the searchBar is part of the Tableview, so if you hide the Tableview you also end up hiding the searchBar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the search results of a `UISearchController` appear in a new `UITableView` of your choice, do this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: myTableViewController)
```

instead of this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Passing a view controller to the constructor allows the `UISearchController` to display the view controller at appropriate times (i.e. when the search is active). This is what you need to do.

Passing `nil` means, *I'm using my own view controller (and table view)*.

Comment: Yes, you could make it in the storyboard, give it a Storyboard ID, and instantiate it in code using the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(_:)` function of `UIStoryboard`.

Comment: should I set the delegate of the `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol to the collectionview or the tableview?

Comment: At a minimum, you only need `UISearchResultsUpdating`, its delegate method `updateSearchResultsForSearchController(_:)` is called whenever the user changes the search text. You can implement this inside your table view controller that you pass to the constructor of `UISearchController` to perform the actual search and reload the table view.

Comment: Excuse me Pirlo or Paulvs, could you please post an example with the full code for this problem which can work perfectly, I'm trying to do the same thing following the Paul's answer but can't work, when I click on the button search, only the searchbar appears on the search controller than if I type something the tableView doesn't appear.