# Show tableview when start typing in searchbar of search controller Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a ViewController A with a MapView and ScrollView and a button for search. If user tap on this button a searcher appears in searchController. I want the search bar to display a new TableView (called TableSearchController) when the user starts to type. I have tried to implement but I have not had any luck dealing with this problem. I would really appreciate any help that can be provided.
I can't find any solution in Google, Youtube, or here, I see some questions but answers can't work like : [How to show tableview when user taps searchbar swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943879/how-to-show-tableview-when-user-taps-searchbar-swift) and [Display table view when searchBar (from searchController) begin edited Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832576/display-table-view-when-searchbar-from-searchcontroller-begin-edited-swift) and [How to make UISearchController's searchResultsController display below the searchbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354926/how-to-make-uisearchcontrollers-searchresultscontroller-display-below-the-searc)

Please how should I do that? Help.

My code for ViewController A :

```
var tableSearchController: TableSearchController!

@IBAction func searchUserAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: tableSearchController)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My TableSearchController which should show after start type in SearchBar :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self

    Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "pseudo").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        [...] // Here I retrieve from Firebase database the nickname of users and put it in an array
        let nickname = userDict["nickname"] as! String // Find username in Firebase
        self.userTab.append(nickname) // And put all username in an array
        self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.userTab.filter { (user:String) -> Bool in
        if user.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
           return true
        } else {
           return false
        }
    }
    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```