# How to replace the content on screen with a tableview when UISearchBar is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I know there's been questions like this before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943879/how-to-show-tableview-when-user-taps-searchbar-swift) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832576/display-table-view-when-searchbar-from-searchcontroller-begin-edited-swift)

But it hasn't gone into much detail, as much as I'd like anyway. I have this 'Explore' page screen sort of thing. It has a search bar at the top and I'd like to show content/posts in the middle section of it. But when the user clicks on the search bar, I want go to a tableview controller, replacing the content on the screen, to show the search results.

[image]

I had a tableviewcontroller embedded in the UIView container:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {


let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
@IBOutlet var searchResultsTableView: UITableView!

var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
var filteredIsers = [NSDictionary?]()
var ref = Database.database().reference()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    ref.child("users").child("public").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let user = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
            let username = user["username"] as? String ?? ""
            if(username == SpalshScreenViewController.UserData.username){
                return
            }else{
                self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
            }
        }else{
            return
        }


        print(self.usersArray)

        // insert rows

        self.searchResultsTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.usersArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic )
    })

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredIsers.count
    }else{
        return self.usersArray.count
    }
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)
}

func filterContent(searchText: String){
    self.filteredIsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
        let username = user!["username"] as? String

        return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let user : NSDictionary?

    if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        user = filteredIsers[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = user?["firstName"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = user?["username"] as? String
    let profilePicUrl = user?["profilePicURL"] as? String
    let encodedurl = URL(string: profilePicUrl!)
    print(profilePicUrl)
    cell.imageView!.kf.setImage(with: encodedurl, placeholder: UIImage(named: "profile_pic"))

    return cell
}
}
```

Would I have that code in it's separate UITableViewController and then present that view when the search bar is clicked or?

I know you'd change the `let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` to something like `let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: tableViewController)`

but I don't know how to tie everything in. In my `searchViewController` I have reference to the UISearchBar, I was thinking I'd add a tap gesture onto it and `present` a the tablecontrollerview when it's clicked but that would mean there would be an inconsistency in animation and search bar style?

EDIT:

So basically, I have a view controller, in that view controller I have a search bar at the top (doing nothing at the moment) and underneath that search bar will be a collection view full of different posts. When the user clicks on the search bar I'd like to replace that collection view with a table view with the results of the search result. How would I achieve that?

Comment: Once again: Do not use `NSDictionary/NSArray` in Swift. You throw away the type information. Use always native types. To get the nice table view animation use the diffable data source API introduced in iOS 13

Comment: That wasn't just my code, I used someone else's to test, I'll update all of that once I have a working feature as I described above. I'd prefer to have a working feature now over nice animations.

Comment: Please check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687827/1438311
There's a little animation and code example that probably does exactly what you need.

Comment: @Peter oh wow that looks like exactly what I want! Will I be able to replace the first initial table view for a collection view of some sort? I have a view controller, in that view controller I have a search bar at the top (doing nothing at the moment) and underneath that search bar will be a collection view full of different posts. When the user clicks on the search bar I'd like to replace that collection view with a table view with the results of the search result.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up *searchResultsController* and *searchResultsUpdater* properties of the [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller) class

Concerning UISearchBar object, you have to use the one which comes with UISearchController and add it programmatically to a view.

```
view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

Comment: can you provide examples or something? Would I still use the UISearchBar object in my explore view or? I'm trying to achieve something like instagrams explore page.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @nathan if you can please explain in more details than it would be better. Other wise on base of my current understanding. If you have search bar added in top of view and you have the table view in it also then you can update your table view in search bar delegate methods. I am sharing the search bar delegate methods for your help.

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let str = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        viewModel?.search(text: str)
        tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if let t = searchBar.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
        if t.count > 0 {
            viewModel?.addNewSearch(text: t)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    viewModel?.cancel()
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
} }
```

I have used MVVM in my code so ViewModel is basically used for data update and changes. Thanks you can ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: I have a view controller, in that view controller I have a search bar at the top (doing nothing at the moment) and underneath that search bar will be a collection view full of different posts. When the user clicks on the search bar I'd like to replace that collection view with a table view with the results of the search result.

Comment: @NathanEllis you can do it in textDidChange method of search bar delegate.

One solution is you can place the tableview beyond of collection view and connect its IBOutlet and write your table view delegates. When search bar comes to textdidchange delegate method you can unhide tableview and reload its data  accordingly.